# How to get square cropped photo thumbnail in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, thumbnails, photo

I want to get a photo thumbnail for my collection view cell, this is how i did it:

```
imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset as! PHAsset, targetSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        cell.setThumbnail(result!)
    }   
})
```

This will get a thumbnail that is stretched, I want a square cropped thumbnail that keeps the photo's original ratio like iPhone's Photo app did.

Any ideas? Please respond in swift, because I am new to ios programming, and I start with swift, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Interface Builder where you can set the properties on your `UIImageView`, take a look at these two properties:

[image]

The view mode will affect whether it looks stretched or if it fits. Sometimes, though, even though it technically fits, it may still overflow the bounds of the cell rect if your image is too big. In that case, you can enable "Clip Subviews" which will make sure the image does not display outside the bounds of the image view rect.

If you are not using Interface Builder, both of these properties can be set on the cell in code instead, i.e.:

```
// This is assuming your UIImageView inside your cell is
// called 'thumbnail'. You could put this code inside of your
// .setThumbnail() function instead--though it's not clear
// what all that is doing from you code snippet.
cell.thumbnail.clipsToBounds = true
cell.thumbnail.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

The various content modes you can choose from are defined like this in UIKit:

```
public enum UIViewContentMode : Int {

    case ScaleToFill
    case ScaleAspectFit // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    case ScaleAspectFill // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    case Redraw // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    case Center // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    case Top
    case Bottom
    case Left
    case Right
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
}
```